# Package expect is not installed in gnome connectiom manager

Tags: networking, apt, gnome, dpkg, expect

I'm trying to install gnome connection manager after installation following process comes.

```
sudo dpkg -i gnome-connection-manager_1.2.0_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-connection-manager.
(Reading database ... 171778 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack gnome-connection-manager_1.2.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-connection-manager (1.2.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-connection-manager:
 gnome-connection-manager depends on expect; however:
  Package expect is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-connection-manager (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-connection-manager
```

When I clicked to launch the gnome connection manager icon the message come "You must install expect"
Kindly guide me how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

The error message tell you that you must install `expect` package .

so the simple way to do is `apt-get install expect` .

Why did you not run `apt-get install gnome-connection-manager`  ?

**apt-get** will download and install all depencies